# SaaS application using firestore's offline cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an ionic4 firestore mobile app. It's a SaaS application it has monthly subscription payments. My problem is how could I sell the app using firestore's offline capabilities? I mean making the app work offline adds value to my product but the users can use it for ever, with just offline caching. How can I stop users from using it after a month? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted the opposite (allowing the user to continue using the app offline, but not online, after their subscription expires), you could do so by modeling this in the server-side security rules of your database.

But security rules are not applied while the client is offline. So there's no way to use security rules to reject users without a subscription.

This means you'll have to find a way to lock them out of your app itself, typically by storing (in the offline cache) until when their subscription is valid, and then refusing to start the app if that date is in the past.

A malicious user might be able to work around this, and access the data without your app. Since you're not paying for any database services at this point, that seems a decent trade-off. But if you don't think so, you can start looking at encrypting the data, which makes it harder for users to access the cache without your app. At this point you're pretty much in an arms race with malicious users though, so I'd seriously consider if the loss in potential revenue is worth the effort.

Comment: You are right, client-side security can be bypassed.  I am thinking of using a cordova plugin called Secure Storage to fix it. But I haven't used it before.